# WSL 2: Unable to install kali linux - WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80370102

Tags: linux, virtualization, windows-subsystem-for-linux, kali-linux, hp

I'm trying to install Kali as Windows Subsystem for Linux. I get below error:

> WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80370102
> Please enable the Virtual Machine Platform Windows feature and ensure virtualization is enabled in the BIOS.

My Spesifications:

```
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Home
OS Version:                10.0.19045 N/A Build 19045
OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
OS Configuration:          Standalone Workstation
OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
...
System Manufacturer:       Hewlett-Packard
System Model:              HP ENVY TS 15 Notebook PC
System Type:               x64-based PC
Processor(s):              1 Processor(s) Installed.
                           Intel64 Family 6 Model 60 Stepping 3 GenuineIntel ~2100 Mhz
BIOS Version:              Insyde F.72, 6/26/2018
...
Total Physical Memory:     12,220 MB
Available Physical Memory: 9,729 MB
Virtual Memory: Max Size:  14,076 MB
Virtual Memory: Available: 11,844 MB
Virtual Memory: In Use:    2,232 MB
...
Hyper-V Requirements:      VM Monitor Mode Extensions: Yes
                           Virtualization Enabled In Firmware: Yes
                           Second Level Address Translation: Yes
                           Data Execution Prevention Available: Yes
```

1. Updated BIOS to the latest version
2. Virtualizaion is enabled In BIOS at boot
3. Windows Features are on (hyper V / Virtualization)

**Screenshots**

[image]
[image]
[image]

**What** could possibly be wrong?

Comment: Are you installing Kali Linux from the Microsoft Store ?

Comment: yes, dowloaded from microsoft store.

Comment: Your screenshots don’t indicate if Virtual Machine Platform has been installed or not so determine if it has n edit your question

Comment: Is the BIOS "Virtualization Technology" enabled ?

Comment: @harrymc - Yes; The author made that fact clear. The error suggests that VMP is disabled.

Comment: Downvoters should feel obliged to post an answer showing effective use of Kali in WSL.

Comment: (1) Do you have in the BIOS, under Security, an option for "Enable vtx technology"? (2) Have you enabled the Windows feature of Virtual Machine Platform?

Comment: Updated Screenshots. Virtulaization is enabled in every possible way. I tried also to run commands from PowerShell and CMD as Administrator to make sure nothing blocks the operation but still have same error!

Comment: "Virtualizaion is enabled In BIOS at boot"  Why does the screenshot say disabled?

Answer (score -2):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/wsl/install-manual#step-4---download-the-linux-kernel-update-package

try these steps it worked for me

Comment: Just update your wsl

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1218708)